# How to make Ransack search between classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, transactions, ransack

Let's say I have following models:

```
User
has_many :accounts

Account
belongs_to :user
has_many :transactions

Transaction
belongs_to :account
belongs_to :user
```

I have made the columns "account_id" in the table transactions, "user_id" in accounts.

How can I make searches in transactions using Ransack, passing by filter the attribute name of the user? Basically, I want to make a search field that receive a name and have to return all the transactions of the accounts thats belongs that user.

But, for what I see, Ransack just let me make searches in columns in their respective tables.

Like, I can find account_id searching in transactions using:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
<%= f.label :account_id_eq, 'Account ID:' %>
<%= f.text_field :account_id_eq %>
```

So if I want to get all the transactions using the filter user's name, I will have to create a foreign key user_name in the table transaction?
Or there is another way to do that.
Sorry if I could not explain my problem well, "meu inglês não é muito bom"

Answer (score 1):

Ransack allows search by associations. Try to pass `account_user_name_eq`.